# Multi-threading on UI Thread

Tags: java, android, multithreading, timer, scheduled-tasks

I need to update 6 graphs real-time. So I create a separate queue for every single graph and try to update it with timer.schedule but it does not really work. In particular, if I comment calls of every single timer.schedule and leave only the first one it works well. But even if I add second timer.schedule (so 1 and 2 timers only) it freezes. Here is the code I use:

```
timer_graph1 = new Timer();
timer_graph1.schedule(new Graph1(), 20, 20);
timer_graph2 = new Timer();
timer_graph2.schedule(new Graph2(), 20, 20);
timer_graph3 = new Timer();
timer_graph3.schedule(new Graph3(), 20, 20);
timer_graph4 = new Timer();
timer_graph4.schedule(new Graph4(), 20, 20);
timer_graph5 = new Timer();
timer_graph5.schedule(new Graph5(), 20, 20);
timer_graph6 = new Timer();
timer_graph6.schedule(new Graph6(), 20, 20);

class Graph1 extends TimerTask {

    public void run() {

        runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                //add data to the graph and update
                mChart1.invalidate();
            }
        });

    }
}

//same structure as for Graph1
class Graph2 extends TimerTask {

}
```

Could you please suggest what's wrong with this approach?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, but can you explain *does not really work* mean ?

Comment: In particular, if I comment calls of every single timer.schedule and leave only first one it works well. But even if I add second timer.schedule (so 1 and 2 timer only) it freezes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your code I can tell either your refreshing isn't updated to GUI or your GUI is blinking fast.

The rule of thumb on updating GUI is:

1. Update data at backend by separate thread(s). Use double buffering if needed.
2. Invoke all GUI update inside `SwingUtilities.invokeLater()` so the update is done inside EDT thread.

Comment: IIRC `invalidate` is safe to call on any thread; it tells the main thread to redraw this component later.

Comment: @immibis It is. I haven't touched Java GUI for a while so thanks for remind me.